# Lock Z-rotation in cinemachine

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I have a problem with freezing rotation in z axis. There is an airplane and a cinemachine free look camera is attached to it. When the plane rotates along the Z axis, the camera rotates with it. Is it possible to somehow block only one axis of rotation in cenimachine camera?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Transposer>World Space. Because we have a problem, if the cinemachine is a child of the object, the rotation will happen, according to the orientation of the Z axis. I had the same problem. Mixing object rotation' (either for a simple movement or some rotation command), which is attached to the cinemachine camera, doesn't seem to be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Need Change the binding mode to Lock To Target No Roll